# How do I resolve this issue using Calendar and ComboBox with PrimeFaces?

Tags: jquery, css, spring, jsf, primefaces

I use a PrimeFaces form with InputTexts, ComboBoxes and Calendars, but I have a problem when I select a date in Calender or a value from the ComboBox.

[Screen Capture](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxYa1FwIsMrdYUVoak55ajVCb3M/edit).

Form code:

```
<h:form id="edit">
    <p:dialog header="Ajout de Personne" widgetVar="personneAjout" 
              resizable="false" id="editP" modal="true"
              style="height: 1000px !important ; width:1000px !important">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="false" life="10000" />
        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4"
              style="margin:0 auto ; height: 400px !important; width:250px !important">
        <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputLabel for="hed1" value="Formulaire d'ajout de personnel " id="hed1" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:outputLabel for="personnelMat" title="Nom" value="Matricule :" 
                   style=" color: crimson;" />
        <h:inputText value="#{personnelBean.personnel.matricule}" id="personnelMat" required="true" 
                 requiredMessage="Vous devez remplir le champs Matricule." style=" margin: 0; padding: 5px;" />
        <p:outputLabel for="nom" title="Nom" value="Nom:" style="color: crimson;" />
        <h:inputText value="#{personnelBean.personnel.nom}" id="nom" required="true" requiredMessage="Vous devez remplir le champs Nom."/>
        <p:outputLabel for="prenom" value="Prenom:" style="color: crimson;" />
        <h:inputText value="#{personnelBean.personnel.prenom}" id="prenom" required="true" requiredMessage="Vous devez remplir le champs Prenom."/>
        <p:outputLabel for="personneDateEmbauche" title="Nom" value="Date d'embauche" style="color: crimson;" />
        <h:outputLabel for="diplome" title="Nom" value="Diplome" style="color: crimson;" />
        <p:calendar value="#{personnelBean.personnel.dateEmbauche}" id="personneDateEmbauche" required="true" />
        <h:inputText value="#{personnelBean.personnel.diplome}" id="diplome" required="true" style=" width : 208px; height  : 26px; color: crimson;" />
        <h:outputText value="Grade : " style="color: crimson;" />
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{personnelBean.personnel.grade}" style="width: 134px ! important;">
             <f:selectItem itemLabel="Technicien" itemValue="Technicien" />
             <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cadre" itemValue="Cadre" />
             <f:selectItem itemLabel="Administratif" itemValue="Administratif" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:outputLabel for="personnelserv" title="Nom" value="Service :" style="color: crimson;" />
        <h:inputText value="${personnelBean.service}" id="personnelserv" />
        <p:outputLabel for="personnelpost" title="Nom" value="Poste :" style="color: crimson;" />
        <h:inputText value="${personnelBean.poste}" id="personnelpost" />


        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:separator />

        <p:commandButton value="Enregistrer"
                         update=":a:AjoutTab, growl"
                         actionListener="#{personnelBean.ajoutp(actionEvent)  }"
                         oncomplete="personneAjout.hide()" />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Comment: And the problem is? By the way, how's this question related to jQuery, CSS or Spring?

Comment: i don't know if that problem related to my CSS template or some functions of jQuery cuz primeface based on jQuery and Ajax ! Spring cuz i use it with primeface (both) ! for the problem if u see the screen capture that for example the calandre is very small like a Matrix of points ! the same for the comboBox

Comment: What's the scope of your managed bean? Or are your beans managed by Spring and you're storing them in session?

Comment: in my bean i have @SessionScoped ! it's not managed by Spring

Comment: i have this annotations in my personnelBean.java
@ManagedBean(name = "personnelBean")
@SessionScoped